# I need to copy data from 3 sheets to another master sheet in same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have written a code for this but getting an error

`The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 44)`

Code:

```
function updateMaster() {
var repArray  = new Array();
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
 // build array of all sheets
 for (i in allSheets) {                              
   if ((allSheets[i].getName()).match(/.*?\-Rep$/))
      {repArray.push(allSheets[i].getName());}
 }

 // store all sheets in array
 var sheetArray = [];   
 // loop through all rep sheets                             
 for (var j in repArray) {       
   // get each sheet                    
   var tempSheet  = ss.getSheetByName(repArray[j]);  
       // get sheet data
   var dataRange  = tempSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
   // remove the first header row
   dataRange.splice(parseInt(0), 1);                 
       // append sheet data to array
   var sheetArray = sheetArray.concat(dataRange);    
 }

 // Time to update the master sheet
 var mSheet    = ss.getSheetByName("summary");        
 // save top header row
 var headerRow = mSheet.getRange(1,1,1,12).getValues(); 
 // clear the whole sheet
 mSheet.clear({contentsOnly:true});                 
 // put back the header row 
 mSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 12).setValues(headerRow);
```

This is where i am getting error while writing to master sheet:

```
 // write to the Master sheet via the array 
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray);
  // force spreadsheet updates
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();                   
 // pause (1,000 milliseconds = 1 second)          
 Utilities.sleep("200");                             

 // delete empty rows at bottom
 var last = mSheet.getLastRow();                     
 var max  = mSheet.getMaxRows();
 if (last !== max) {mSheet.deleteRows(last+1,max-last);}

}
```

I am not able to figure out the error.

Comment: first guess it that you are trying to delete rows that are out of bounds, or invalid numbers, what are the values of last and max?

Comment: leave that part that is not giving any error it gives error in mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray);      The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid.

Comment: you confused me by saying "this is where i get the error" and then put another piece of code. Now this is even clearer: you don't have to get a range with number of columns/rows to set the data, just use a range with row and column reference, like this: mSheet.getRange(1,1).setValues(headerRow);

Comment: I tried that when i used  mSheet.getRange(2, 1).setValues(sheetArray); i got error "Incorrect range height, was 0 but should be 1"

Comment: Depends on what you need to put in: sheetArray or headerRow. In your question, it states: setValues(headerRow) and in your previous comment you say: setValues(sheetArray).

Comment: i am getting the error here                                          // write to the Master sheet via the array 
 mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray);

Comment: I see, what dimensions is sheetArray?

Comment: Thanks djerry for your support but i resolved the problem

Comment: If any of my answer helped, could you mark as answer and perhaps you should post you solution here so other people could benefit from this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a sheet with "Rep" inside the name.

"The first array stores all the Sales Rep sheets.  Since some sheets could be something other than Sales Rep sheets, the script stores sheets only if the sheet name has a “-Rep” suffix (e.g. “JohnDoe-Rep”)"

code source: http://blog.ditoweb.com/2012/01/consolidate-spreadsheet-sheets-with.html

That's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

mSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetArray.length, 12).setValues(sheetArray)

I faced the same issue and solved it by following the "Rep" solution. Then I ran into another problem and realized that my number of columns was different... so just go back in and change the no 12 to the number of rows you have in your sheet.

Also try to keep the format of the all sheets the same.

Rename the sheet where you would like the data to combine