# Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,12) what does the numbers in bracket specify?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

```
Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,12)
```

I cannot understand the arguments `1,1,1,12` . What is this - the sheet id or row or what?

```
method getRange(row, column, optNumRows, optNumColumns)
```

here what does `optNumRows` and `optNumColumns` mean???

Comment: Thinking logically, the row would be the start row and the optNumRows will be the number of rows from there, and the opt meaning you don't have to specify these parameters, so you could also type in the first 2 parameters without specifying the number of rows/cols (so you get B5 for example).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply can you please look this for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946500/i-need-to-copy-data-from-3-sheets-to-another-master-sheet-in-same-spreadsheet

Comment: Maybe this wasn't documented in 2012, but now [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` is clearly documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Found these docu on the [google docu pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns):

- row ---          int --- top row of the range
- column ---           int---  leftmost column of the range
- optNumRows ---   int --- number of rows in the range.
- optNumColumns ---    int --- number of columns in the range

In your example, you would get (if you picked the 3rd row) "C3:O3", cause C --> O is 12 columns

**edit**

Using the example on the docu:

> // The code below will get the number of columns for the range C2:G8
>
> // in the active spreadsheet, which happens to be "4"
>
> var count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getNumColumns();
> Browser.msgBox(count);

The values between brackets:

2: the starting row = 2

3: the starting col = C

6: the number of rows = 6 so from 2 to 8

4: the number of cols = 4 so from C to G

So you come to the range: C2:G8

Comment: as per google: // The code below will get the number of columns for the range C2:G8
// in the active spreadsheet, which happens to be "4"
var count = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, 6, 4).getNumColumns();
Browser.msgBox(count);

Comment: that's just because they specify an extra call on the getrange, i.e. getNumColumns. you see they have 2,3,6,4 with the 4 being the number of columns in the range, and that's what they show in the msgbox.

Comment: to add to this answer, once you have the range you can get the values using getValues() (or getValue if you care about a single cell).

Besides getting the values you can get many other things, look at the linked doc in the answer.

Comment: I have an r1=0 c1=0 r2=3 c2=3 how to get range(0,0,3,3) will give error

Answer (score 50):

I know this is an older thread but I thought a graphic might help see this visually.

getRange(row, column, optNumRows, optNumColumns)

[image]