# Correct use of getRange and getLastRow for source and target ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If someone could help me **understand** getRange please. I have read many responses on here and the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) but am still confused as to how it works. (I'm a beginner coder as you can see)

***How do I reference a specific row in a data set with getRange?***

- I have a table of data in A1:D10
- I would like to copy one row A5:D5

I have tried the below but get an error. *"number of rows in data does not match the number of rows in the range"*. Could someone explain how to reference a specific row?

```
 function copyPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

// this is me referencing that row

```
  var sourceRange = source.getRange("A5:D5");
```

// the rest

```
  var data = sourceRange.getValues();
  var lr = sourceRange.getLastRow();
  var lc = sourceRange.getLastColumn();
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")

target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1,1,lr,lc).setValues(data);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,12) what does the numbers in bracket specify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947590/sheet-getrange1-1-1-12-what-does-the-numbers-in-bracket-specify) This question has **147k**  views by the way and appears as one of the top threads in google. It is really hard to miss it.

Comment: I did look at this, thank you. I tried to implement it, but could not understand why my script did not work. However I realise now (after getting an answer here) that my problem was not that I didn't understand getRange - but that I misunderstood how to reference my source range and use of getLastColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You should provide the number of rows and columns when calling [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).

You are providing the indexes of the last row and column of `A5:D5` (that is, `lr=5`, `lc=4`), when you should provide the number of rows and columns of the source range (`lr=1`, `lc=4`). Because of this, the source and destination ranges don't match dimensions, and you are getting this error.

#### Solutions:

Therefore, this can be fixed by changing these two lines:

```
var lr = sourceRange.getLastRow();
var lc = sourceRange.getLastColumn();
```

To these ones:

```
var lr = sourceRange.getNumRows();
var lc = sourceRange.getNumColumns();
```

An alternative option would be to use the `data` dimensions (using [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length#:%7E:text=The%20length%20property%20of%20an,highest%20index%20in%20the%20array.)):

```
target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

#### Reference:

- [getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows)
- [getNumColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns)

Comment: Thank you so much for this thoughtful answer - not only did you solve my immediate problem, but the additional information you provided has set me up for better success going forward.

Comment: @Mardi-LouiseVanHeerden You're welcome. I'm glad my answer was helpful.