# How do I resolve the getrange error "The number of rows in the range must be at least 1"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below line of code is throwing an error
`var FillDownRange = bp.getRange(2, 6, lr-1);`

**Error Message**

> Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.

Why would I be receiving this error message?

Here is the full function:

```js
function ProcessBlueprint() {
  //Formula: What is the top query for the URL?
  bp.getRange("F2").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,GSC!$A$2:$F,2,false),)");
  var FillDownRange = bp.getRange(2, 6, lr-1);
  bp.getRange("F2").copyTo(FillDownRange);
}
```

Comment: Your "lr" variable is probably 1 (or less). you can try using debugger or logger to check it.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

`lr-1` is smaller than `1`. Make sure your sheet has at least two rows.

- Right now it has either `0` or `1`, assuming that `lr` is calculated by [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

**Solution:**

You can avoid the issue with a simple `if` condition:

```
  bp.getRange("F2").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,GSC!$A$2:$F,2,false),)");
  if(lr>1){
    var FillDownRange = bp.getRange(2, 6, lr-1);
    bp.getRange("F2").copyTo(FillDownRange);
  }
```

Another idea would be to use `2` if the last row is `0` or `1`:

```
  bp.getRange("F2").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,GSC!$A$2:$F,2,false),)");
  const fr = lr>1?lr:2;
  var FillDownRange = bp.getRange(2, 6, fr-1);
  bp.getRange("F2").copyTo(FillDownRange);
```

Make sure to understand what the arguments inside `getRange` represent:

[Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,12) what does the numbers in bracket specify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947590/sheet-getrange1-1-1-12-what-does-the-numbers-in-bracket-specify)