# Need to find a way for data entry to start after a specific row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my script:

```
function CopyRange() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EA2F99W1lpgTzX3zoTNpzuEXWh-mDkvo9UyZC4kDNtQ'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('UKG-A'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange('G4:K4'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EA2F99W1lpgTzX3zoTNpzuEXWh-mDkvo9UyZC4kDNtQ'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('UKG-A'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(7 && ts.getLastRow()+1,15,1,5).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
 

}
```

The code works as normal. When I run the code it get data from source sheet and enter on the destination sheet after the last row which has data. But what i want is to define a specific row to start data entry and continue from that row. For example I want data entry to start After the 7th row of `UKG-A` sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Explanation:**

Your goal is to add a new row after row seven and then set the new data on this newly created row.

- you can use [insertRowAfter(afterPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowAfter(Integer)) to insert a new row after a specified position.
- start pasting from row `8`.
- (optional) dynamically get the length of `data` instead of hardcopying the size.

### Solution:

**Change:**

```
ts.getRange(7 && ts.getLastRow()+1,15,1,5).setValues(data);
```

**to:**

```
ts.insertRowAfter(7)
ts.getRange(8,15,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

**Related:**

- [Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,12) what does the numbers in bracket specify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947590/sheet-getrange1-1-1-12-what-does-the-numbers-in-bracket-specify)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Thank you, The code copy the data to row 8. but it keeps over writing the value. what i want is when ever i ran the code it should copy the value to a new row.

Comment: Marios thank you so much for your help. your solution work. But this method create an issue. The issue is i have some data in column A to M in between rows 1 to 33. If i use this method the data in A to M also move down. Is there something like that i can find the last row of column O starting from 6th row and +1 like the original script i have. Thank you.

Comment: @Riufaan thanks for your comment. Could you please post a new question regarding the issue. Stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. In this way, future readers will benefit from both questions. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sure. I m really sorry for the inconvenience.