# How to increment the new data to the last row?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create an Apps Script function to update the new data at the last row of a range in Google Sheet. My sheet "import" is currently empty and I have the following error when I add my function ImportPrivacyTagCo() into A1 cell : "Exception: Range not found".

```
function ImportPrivacyTagCo() {
  
var cellVal= '=IMPORTJSON("myAPIurl")';

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('import');
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

sheet.getRange(lastrow).setValues([cellVal]);

}
```

Do you have any idea to fix this error ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at how the [.getRange()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947590/sheet-getrange1-1-1-12-what-does-the-numbers-in-bracket-specify) is working.

You need to add the column number. Also it looks like you want to set a formula In that case, use [.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) instead.

```
function ImportPrivacyTagCo() {
  
var cellVal= '=IMPORTJSON("myAPIurl")';

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('import');
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1).setFormula(cellVal)

}
```