# How to obtain a specified row from a Google Sheet from doGet with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm not understanding this output, in that, as expected, the `row` parameter is being passed to `doGet`.  Why is the `read` function only [returning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11947590/4531180) row #3, which is shown as A3, and not returning the expected range?

Clearly the `row` variable is being output to `HTML` correctly.  Why is the `range` not using that value as expected?

[image: output]

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>iterator</h1>
  <form action="<?= url ?>" method="GET">
    note <input type="text"  name="update" />
    <br>
    row <input type="text"  name="row" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" /><br> <br> <br>
    <span><?= params ?></span> <br> <br> <br>
    <span><?= update ?></span> <br> <br>
    <span><?= row  ?></span> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <span><?= values ?></span> <br>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Contents of `Code.js`:

```
const sheetID = "1DalaGJ3rGHmagpUqq3aOXSKRkyZQapfw-bCNTW5lgBE";
const sheetName = "data";

function doGet(e) {
  var row = 3;
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  htmlOutput.params = params;
  htmlOutput.update = 'updated value is: ' + e.parameter['update'];
  htmlOutput.row = 'row is: ' + e.parameter['row'];
  htmlOutput.values = read(row);
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function read(row) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
  var data = sheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = data.getRange(row,1,1,3);
  var values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  return values;
}

function getUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}
```

The logs show data of of:

```
Oct 10, 2022, 8:11:43 PM
Info
[[A3, B3, C3]]
```

whereas I would expect to see A1, B1, C1 instead, as contained in the spreadhseet.  Why is `row` staying at the initial value?  The odd part, is that the output to HTML would indicated the the variable is **mutable**.

*This is towards `CRUD` operations on the spreadsheet.  Here, looking to read a row specified by the user.*

*I've tried changing variable names, it doesn't seem to a scope issue.*

Comment: You are not assigning `e.parameter['row']` to variable `row`, that's why it stays at the initial value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` is returning only row 3 because the variable `row` was declared in this line `var row = 3;`. Between this line and the call to `read(row)` there is nothing changing the value assigned to the `row` variable.

If you are struggling with reading code, avoid reusing the same sequences of characters like `row` to name multiple elements, in this case:

- server side variable
- HtmlTemplate property
- Template HTML variable (used inside scriptlets)
- URL parameter,

Instead use unique sequences for each of them except for HtmlTemplate property and the Template HTML variable as they should use the same.