# How to change the value of a hidden HTML field from within Google Apps Script using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

Previously, the `row` variable was [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74022583/4531180) entered with:

```
row <input type="text"  name="row" />
```

**How is that parameter, which is now marked [hidden](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_hidden.asp), made mutable, as when the `type` was `input` as above?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>iterator</h1>
  <form action="<?= url ?>" method="GET">
    note <input type="text"  name="update" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" /><br> <br> <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="row" value="3487">
    <span><?= params ?></span> <br> <br> <br>
    <span><?= update ?></span> <br> <br>
    <span><?= row  ?></span> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <span><?= values ?></span> <br>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

The notion is to iterate through the row's of a spreadsheet, and so the row should increment each time it's used (or the submit button is clicked).  To increment the value it must be **mutable** and then sent back as a parameter to `Code.js` where it's used to query the `Google Sheet`.

Would this be accomplished with a `<script>` tag, [perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16616998/4531180)?

Answer (score 2):

You might use JavaScript and the DOM API on the client-side, but first, you might take advantage of the id attribute

```
<input id="something" type="hidden" name="row" value="3487">
```

Then in use JavaScript / DOM API to change the value as follow:

```
document.querySelector('#something').value = "3488";
```

You should add the above line in appropriate place in your HTML. It might be on onclick attribute of a button, in a `<script>`, as part of function called someway, i.e. by clicking a button. To call the function you might use button `onclick` attribute to set the function to be called or use `HtmlElement.addEventListener` to set the function to be called when the element event occurs.

Another option is to use a scriptlet as you have done in the `<span>`'s, but instead of adding it as the tag content, put the scriptlet instead of the default value:

```
<input  type="hidden" name="row" value="<?!= valueFromServerSide ?>">
```

Please note the use of `!`, this is to indicate that should not use contextual escaping, in other words, to add the value assigned to the variable as is.

Related

- [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348494/1595451)

Comment: where you use the `#something` syntax, would that be in the `HTML` document?

Comment: Yes. The DOM API is available on the client-side, not in the server side.

Comment: Added another option

Comment: I'm intrigued by the scriptlet you mentioned.  This is a proprietary feature from Google Apps Script?  Referencing:  https://codewithcurt.com/how-to-link-between-google-web-app-pages/ although I haven't yet had time to digest the info.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but I don't think. Java uses `<% %>`, PHP use `<?php ?>`/ `<? ?>` and other languages might use something similar to embed server-side scripting in html files